# Necessary condition for orbits to be separated by invariant polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory

Suppose we have an algebraic subgroup $G \subset GL(V)$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. I'm trying to prove the following:

> If $G$-orbits in $V$ can be separated by $G$-invariant polynomials, then $G$ is finite.

I've found out that it's important that the field is $\mathbb{C}$ (I think because $\mathbb{C}$ is closed). Over $\mathbb{R}$ we have a counterexample $SO_1 \subset GL(\mathbb{R}^3)$. But the requirement for subgroup to be algebraic prevented me to construct something of this kind for $\mathbb{C}$. So this condition is also crucial.

I have a feeling it's an easy question, but I didn't succeed in making all those conditions work together. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take homogeneous generators $f_1, \dots, f_n$ of $\mathbb{C}[V]^G$ and consider a map $f : V \to \mathbb{C}^n$, $f(x) = (f_1(x), \dots, f_n(x))$. Since invariant polynomials separate $0$ from other orbits, $f^{-1}(0) = 0$. This condition together with homogeneity implies that $f$ has finite fibers (it is actually finite, [When does a homogeneous morphism have only finite fibers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241333/when-does-a-homogeneous-morphism-have-only-finite-fibers)). Hence all orbits are finite. Hence $G$ is finite.

Comment: What if $G$ is not reductive?